# LazyColumn in jetpack compose does not recompose when list data changes, but forloop over data list works, I am not getting why and what is happening

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn, mutablestateof, statelist

I am developing a app using jetpack compose, and I am new to this UI framework,
I want to display the categories amountSpent property.
I am changing the amount spend in dialog and want to reflect the change in list, Here issue is the Lazy Column does not recompose but Text inside categories forloop works.
I am not sure why Lazy Column is not working but simple forloop is working

```
          var categories = remember {
            mutableStateListOf(
              Category.FoodCategory(amountSpent=100),
              Category.ShoppingCategory(amountSpent=50),
              Category.TransportationCategory(amountSpent=80),
              Category.EducationCategory(amountSpent=90)
            )
          }

categories[0].amountSpent=400
```

```
@Composable
fun HomeUi(categories: SnapshotStateList<Category>) {
         
LazyColumn() {
items(categories){
  Text(text = it.amountSpent.toString())
   }
}
categories.forEach{
  Text(text = it.amountSpent.toString())
}
}
```

I was expecting that Lazy Column and ForEach world result the same but to my shock Lazy Column did not work

```
The Output was
Before 
100
50
90
80
100
50
90
80

After Change
100
50
90
80
400
50
90
80
```

Code for category:

```
sealed class Category(
  val name: String,
  val totalBudget:Int,
  open var amountSpent: Int,
  @DrawableRes val icon : Int){
  data class FoodCategory(override var amountSpent: Int=0):
    Category("Food",500,amountSpent,R.drawable.ic_food)
  class ShoppingCategory(override var amountSpent: Int=0):
    Category("Shopping",500,0,R.drawable.ic_shopping)
  class TransportationCategory(override var amountSpent: Int=0):
    Category("Transportation",500,amountSpent,R.drawable.ic_transportation)
  class EducationCategory(override var amountSpent: Int=0):
    Category("Education",500,amountSpent,R.drawable.ic_education)

}
```

Edit Fixed the Issue:
I had to remove the category form list and add it again so that the lazy column re-compiles, assigning value to it does not work,

Please can anyone explain if is this a bug from Jetpack compose or an issue from my side?

```
var categoryChanged = categories.find { cat == it.name }
                  categoryChanged?.amountSpent = categoryChanged?.amountSpent?.plus(400)!!
                  var ind = categories.indexOf(categoryChanged)
                  categories.remove(categoryChanged)
                  categories.add(ind, categoryChanged!!)
```

Comment: Could share code for `Category`

Comment: @Rasul i have updated the Category code

Answer (score 0):

if you need a change item position or update value in list and you want to recomposition in `LazyColumn`, you have to add `key`.

```
LazyColumn {
    items(
        items = messages,
        key = { message ->
            // Return a stable + unique key for the item
            message.id
        }
    ) { message ->
        MessageRow(message)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check my updated edit of the question. 
I fixed it but would like to know if you have any feedback over the fix